# Fillholes function in Aforge

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I need to use Fillholes function of Aforge, it accepts binary image. I manipulated all pixels to black or white pixels using following code in c#:

```
bitmapimage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(255,255,255));   // for white pixel
bitmapimage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(0,0,0));         // for black pixel
```

But when I apply fillholes  function to bitmap image, I get this exception:

> "Source pixel format is not supported by the filter"

Kindly anyone help why I am getting this exception ... is bitmap image not converted to Binary by all using `setpixel`?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the pixel colors will not change the pixel format of your image.

You first need to make sure that you have a gray scale image using some [gray scale filter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm), then make sure that the gray scale image is binary through some [threshold filter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/503a43b9-d98b-a19f-b74e-44767916ad65.htm). Once the image has been pre-processed using these steps, you may apply the [FillHoles](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/68bd57bd-1fd6-6c4e-4500-ed4726bc836e.htm) filter.

*AForge.NET* offers helper classes to merge several filters, so you can combine all three filters into one total filter using the [FiltersSequence](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1bd9732e-de3f-8ac9-1c45-e9c2b526f81d.htm) class.

Assuming that your original `Bitmap` image is named `bitmap`, you can then apply the fill holes filter for example like this:

```
var filter = new FiltersSequence(Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709, 
                                 new Threshold(100), new FillHoles());
var newBitmap = filter.Apply(bitmap);
```

Comment: @amna Any feedback on this answer? Did the solution work for you? If yes, please accept the answer. If no, add information so that your question can be answered more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

AForge FillHoles Class

The filter allows to fill black holes in white object in a binary image. It is possible to specify maximum holes' size to fill using MaxHoleWidth and MaxHoleHeight properties.

The filter accepts binary image only, which are represented as 8 bpp images.
Sample usage:

C#

```
// create and configure the filter
FillHoles filter = new FillHoles( );
filter.MaxHoleHeight = 20;
filter.MaxHoleWidth  = 20;
filter.CoupledSizeFiltering = false;
// apply the filter
Bitmap result = filter.Apply( image );
```

The above was found at http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/68bd57bd-1fd6-6c4e-4500-ed4726bc836e.htm

You have to convert your bitmapImage to a binary image represented as an 8 bpp image. Here is one way to do it.

```
UnmanagedImage grayImage = null;

if (image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
{
    grayImage = bitmapImage;
}
else
{
    grayImage = UnmanagedImage.Create(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
}
```